# ASP.NET MVC DefaultMembership incorrect time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using the default membership provider and i noticed that the lastlockedoutdate was incorrect. It was displaying 2 hours earlier then my local server time.

I thought that the method: ValidateUser was using the database time to set the lastlockedoutdate but the database time is only 1 hour behind. So i am still missing one hour.

Why is the default membershipprovider not using my server time and how can i change it that it uses the correct time?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with MSSQL 2008.

I tested the database time with the following query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Does this have to do with Daylight Savings Time starting not too long ago?  I'd use UTC Time

Comment: Honestly i have no idea, DateTime.Now is displaying the correct time. So my ques is that the membership provider should show correct as well.

Comment: Does your web server and database live on the same machine and if not are their times the same if yes? Does sound like a day light savings time to me. Did you save the time in UTC format?

Comment: When i used DateTime.UtcNow it showed the same time as the lastlockedoutdate, that solved my problem. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it saves as utc datetime, so when i used DateTime.UtcNow it showed the same.